# authorization on wicket component using wicket auth-role

Tags: wicket

I am using wicket 1.4.9 and implemented spring + wicket auth-role and using @AuthorizeInstantiation based on roles on pages. I have multiple custom roles.

I have followed this link to implement the basics:
https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/spring-security-and-wicket-auth-roles.html

After that I have implemented my own UserDetailsService to have my own roles/users from database.

Now, How can I impose controls on  roles with components eg, Links,Buttons ? like
link A can be accessed only by SUPER_USER, DR_MANAGER. (roles comes from database).

I have done like this and it seems to work, but is that the good way to do this? OrbitWebSession is of type AuthenticatedWebSession.

```
        @Override
        public boolean isVisible() {
            if(OrbitWebSession.get().getRoles().hasRole("SUPER_USER")){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

thanks.

Comment: You mention that roles are based on a database query.  Be careful about doing an expensive call in isVisible().  That is an easy computation, but make sure that everything is cached properly.

Comment: okay,Please clarify my confusion, If my custom AunthenticatedWebSession overrdies getRoles() method and if this method gets roles from SecurityContextHolder which loads roles from my UserDetails, isn't it cached? or it is fetching all roles from my User entity on each call?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring; I just meant to make sure that your User object is cached - it would be bad to run a database query every time this method is run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overriding isVisible all the time is a major pain. Take a look at `MetaDataRoleAuthorizationStrategy` instead. You call `authorize(Component component, Action action, String roles)` with `Action RENDER`, and the roles you want to allow. This way the component, whatever it is, is automatically hidden for other roles provided that the authorization strategy is registered in your webapplication. Basically it does the same thing as Holms answer, except you don't have to subclass anything.

Answer (score 3):

You are in the right track, the only change I would do is:

```
@Override
public boolean isVisible() {
    return super.isVisible() && OrbitWebSession.get().getRoles().hasRole("SUPER_USER");
}
```

That way you don't accidentally override its default visible behavior for example if the parent component is not visible.

Comment: This is not the way I would do in Wicket, the other other answers use standard Wicket Authorisation Implementation so better look at them.

Answer (score 3):

Using the @AuthorizeAction annotation you can control wether the component is rendered or not based on roles. It's quite easy to use, but you have to subclass the component that you want to authorize.

```
@AuthorizeAction(action = Action.RENDER, roles = { "SUPER_USER", "DR_MANAGER" })
class UserAdminPageLink extends BookmarkablePageLink<String> {
   //Implementation…
}
add(new UserAdminPageLink("UserAdminPageLink", UserAdminPage.class));
```

Check out [Wicket Examples - Authorization](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/authorization/) for some working code.

Comment: thanks,I will have a look at it. but my application has a lots of component which needs this control.I fear I have to make too many  subclasses !